# How to read Nero InCD CD-RW disks?

Tags: cd, compatibility

I have many CD-RW disks with photos that I want to archive on an external HD, but I can not read them with Ubuntu. How can I read these disks?

> InCD allows you to use your rewritable disc like a big floppy disk. Copy files onto your disc using drag and drop or save them to the disc from other applications.

Answer (score 6):

InCD uses the UDF 2.5 file system which is supported by default. You should be able to access it just like any other CD. However, it seems InCD has the possibility of using a technology called SecurDisk, which probably isn't supported. There is a [program](http://www.nero.com/enu/tools-utilities.html) that allows you to read SecurDisk CDs but it is for Windows. You could try to run it under [wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: +1 for wine. InCD uses some proprietary format based on UDF that AFAIK is not yet hacked (not even the non-free Nero Linux edition seems to support it). InCD is not listed in the wine database. If it does not run there try from a virtual machine (still mabe not supported there as well). My advice: take your CDs to a Windows box and copy to your ext. HD from there.

Comment: The regular InCD format is definitely just standard UDF. It doesn't activate SecurDisk unless you try to enable encryption.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few packages you can try through Synaptic Package Manager if you do a search for UDF. I'm currently trying udftools and libudf0. there is even a package called dares that says that it can rescue damaged CDs and DVDs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [nrg2iso](http://gregory.kokanosky.free.fr/v4/linux/nrg2iso.en.html) can help.

Comment: it's a physical disk, not the nrg.